# store array values from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray

I have two view controllers(viewController and popUpViewController). When i open app, viewController will load. It has buttons. When i click on button, image will be opened in popUpViewController. Then i click close button on popUpViewController,i am dismissing popUpViewController. My scenario is, when i click button in viewController i have to take opened time and i click close button on popUpViewController, i have to take end time.Both should be stored in an array. But array is showing as nil. I am using the following code.

viewController.m

viewDidLoad:

```
fileOpenedValues = @[@"",@"" ,@""];
fileOpenedKeys = @[@"File Name",@"STime",@"ETime"];
fileOpened = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:fileOpenedValues forKeys:fileOpenedKeys];
[fileOpenedArr addObject:fileOpened];


-(void) storeArrayFromPopUp :(NSString *)fname second:(NSString *)mname third:(NSString *)lname
{
 fileOpenedValues = @[fname ,mname ,lname];
 fileOpenedKeys = @[@"File Name",@"STime",@"ETime"];
 fileOpened = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:fileOpenedValues forKeys:fileOpenedKeys];    
 [fileOpenedArr addObject:fileOpened];
}
```

popUpViewController.m

```
[baseObj storeArrayFromPopUp :openedFileName second:fileOpenStime third:fileOpenEtime];
```

After calling storeArrayFromPopUp. fileOpenedArr is showing as nil.

Please advice.

Comment: have you alloc initined fileOpenedArr before adding objects in it..

Comment: how you create basObj.

Comment: yes,In viewdidload itself.

Comment: @ Vishnuvardhan  ViewerViewController *baseObj=[[ViewerViewController alloc]init];

Comment: if you allocating the ViewerVC it will be altogether a new instance. So obviously the array values will be nil.. In your case i would suggest to move the NSArray to global variable. (something like in appdelegate) or a shared instance

Comment: try the traditional method of creating a method that returns the array and calling that method from your other class?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @implementation ViewController {


        NSString *strStartTime;
        NSString *strEndTime;
        NSMutableArray *arrTime;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        arrTime = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        strStartTime = @"";
        strEndTime = @"";
    }

    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        //check start has value means popupview controller was open.
        //viewWillAppear always call when you close the popup.
        if (strStartTime.length > 0) {
            strEndTime = [self getCurrentTime];

            NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:strStartTime,@"StartTime",strEndTime,@"EndTime", nil];
            [arrTime addObject:dic]; //you can have all the start and endtime details in the arrTime array.
            strStartTime = @"";
            strEndTime = @"";
        }
    }

    -(IBAction)btnShowPopupClicked:(id)sender {
        //Set the start time when popup is going to open.
        strStartTime = [self getCurrentTime];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"imagePopup" sender:nil];

    }

-(NSString *)getCurrentTime {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    return currentTime;
}
```